# *ngComponentOutlet - use the injector of the dynamically generated component instance

Tags: angular

I have two components: **WorldComponent** and **ContinentComponent**. They are arranged in the main template like this:

```
<app-world>
  <app-continent></app-continent>
  <app-continent></app-continent>
  <app-continent></app-continent>
<app-world>
```

Then, there is a **WorldService** provided at the WorldComponent's level, responsible to count the number of continents in a world.

The WorldComponent uses its instance of WorldService to print out its own continent count:

---

*world.component.html*

```
<div>
  <h2>A World</h2>
  <p>This World has {{worldService.continentCount}} continents.</p>
</div>
```

---

Each of the WorldComponent's children (the continents) gets this service instance injected so that it can increase the count by 1.

---

*continent.component.ts* (excerpt)

```
export class ContinentComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private worldService: WorldService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.worldService.increaseContinentCount();
  }
}
```

---

For who has worked with AngularJS, basically this is a way to achieve the `require` property of the old Angular 1.5 component, whereas in this case children get a component-level-provided service injected instead of requiring an ancestor's controller. That's why I am not using `@Host` here: `app-continent` happens to be a direct child of `app-world` but could not be the case (imagine we want to count some `<app-country>`s inside the continents instead of the continents).

So far, so good. The template

```
<app-world>
  <app-continent></app-continent>
  <app-continent></app-continent>
  <app-continent></app-continent>
<app-world>
<app-world>
  <app-continent></app-continent>
  <app-continent></app-continent>
<app-world>
```

renders like this:

---

[image: working Worlds]

---

Sorry for the long introduction, now the problem.

### The Problem

I want to add another WorldComponent in a dynamic way by using Angular's `*ngComponentOutlet` directive, so that something like this...

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="WorldComponent">
  <app-continent></app-continent>
  <app-continent></app-continent>
</ng-container>
```

...would render as a world with 2 continents.

The problem is that, by default, the dynamically generated component will use the injector of the host component, which does not have any provider of WorldService.
Even if it had, it would be an application-wide singleton, so it would not be suitable because each World shall obviously have its own continent count.

I know that `*ngComponentOutlet` lets us define a custom injector, so we can do this:

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="WorldComponent; injector: myInjector">
  <app-continent></app-continent>
  <app-continent></app-continent>
</ng-container>
```

but I don't know how to proceed now. I search through all the Angular documentation but I am very new to Angular, so I was not able not figure out how to reach the injector of the component we just dynamically generated, in order to make the dynamic World work like the regular ones.

```
export class AppComponent {
  WorldComponent = WorldComponent;
  myInjector: Injector;

  constructor() {
    //this.myInjector = ?????????
  }
}
```

Please find this example's code [at this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qcvnet?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some helpful info in the angular.io docs: https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet (perhaps it was added/updated since your question was posted).

In your AppComponent constructor, try this: 
`this.myInjector = Injector.create({providers: [{provide: WorldService, deps: []}], parent: injector});`

Comment: I think this is the right direction so I am going to accept it, even though in the specific example the child component "continent" would need to access the provided service, so it gets more complex as projection doesn't work with *ngComponentOutlet. I should use the "content" field but then child components wouldn't get compiled. I bet there are more suitable options to solve that.